# Issue with $scope when used with ng-route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-ng-show

I'm trying to create a login page.When the user login, i want to show some contents like my-profile,settings,help on the navbar.
Currently i'm using ng-show and ng-route.I'm facing an issue with the $scope when using ngroute and ng-show .My $scope variable value doesnot get updated.How can i make it work .Please don't say to refer Angular-js tutorial docs .. Please help with some codes.

Comment: Can you post whole body of $scope.login() function ?

Comment: try $scope.$apply

Comment: i tried it didn't worked .The scope variable is not getting updated

Comment: You need to check call result. Does it call succes or error?